# Dart HTTP Request to Variable

Tags: http, dart, python-requests

I'm trying to put json data into a variable. Why am I getting NULL when I print jsondata?

```
import 'dart:html';
import "dart:convert";

var jsondata;

void main() {

  HttpRequest.getString('file.json').then(
  (result) => jsondata = (JSON.decode(result)));

  print(jsondata);
}
```

When I change jsondata to print seems to work fine and when I use the type command it confirms it as a list. So what am I doing wrong whilst passing to a variable?

```
HttpRequest.getString('file.json').then(
(result) => print(JSON.decode(result))); //this prints fine as type list
```

Answer (score 1):

An `HttpRequest.getString` is an [*asynchronous* method](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures), that is, it doesn't execute immediately - it executes some time in the *future* (and the return type is, in return, `Future<String>`). Consider the following program:

```
print('1');
getData().then((data) => print('2'));
print('3');
```

In a well behaved Dart runtime, this would *never* print '1' '2' '3', but rather would print '1' '3', and *perhaps* print '2' if `getData()` ever *completes* (i.e. no error occurs, no timeouts/internet connectivity problems).

Dart (and other languages) added `await` keyword to make it easier to write programs that *look* synchronous (i.e. don't use nested callbacks that are called "later"), but otherwise behave exactly the same as the previous code:

```
print123() async {
  print('1');
  await getData();
  print('2');
  print('3');
}
```

The above code will, if it is well behaved (again, no timeouts etc), print '1' '2' '3' - exactly what you expected. Now let's apply this same pattern to your code above:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

var jsondata;

main() async {
  jsondata = JSON.decode(await HttpRequest.getString('file.json'));
  print(jsondata);
}
```

You don't *have* to use `await`/`async`, but I find it easier most of the time! If you'd like to keep your current code, make sure to invoke `print` *after* `jsondata` is assigned:

```
main() {
  HttpRequest.getString('file.json').then((data) {
    jsondata = JSON.decode(data);
    print(jsondata);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was very helpful.